# Recursive async function with promise resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, promise, async-await

I have a recursive async function and i can get expected output via `fs.writeFile` where `return new Promise..` is, but cannot return asynchronously. I got undefined. How can I fix that without disrupt my code structure, thanks.

```
async function get_followings(all_data = [], cursor, count = 0) {
    if (count == 2) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve(all_data.length)
      })
    }

    var followings = await client.getFollowings({ userId: 2896863162, first: 50, after: cursor })
    var total = followings.count
    var cursor = followings.page_info.end_cursor
    var data = followings.data

    all_data = all_data.concat(data)

    await get_followings(all_data, cursor, count + 1)
  }

console.log(await get_followings())
```

Comment: One thing I've spotted is that you're not returning the result of `await get_followings`.

Comment: `get_followings` doesn't return anything in the last statement ... so

Comment: also, since this is an async function, you can just `return all_data.length` in that code at the top - no need for that new Promise - as an aside `return Promise.resolve(all_data.length)` is basically what that code is doing ... but as I said, no need to even do that

Comment: @JaromandaX when i try just `return all_data.length` getting undefined again

Comment: huh? you did get rid of `new Promise` right? so it's `if (count==2) return all_data.length` - and you did add a return to the last line (and remove await) that's `return get_followings(all_data, cursor, count + 1)` as the last line

Comment: @JaromandaX worked like that, thanks